# Drop down for state will not validate (php)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Whenever i go to complete the form the drop down for state always shows the error code "your state is required" I need this to be done with so i can continue on to submitting my mysql query.

I think the problem lies within the state drop down itself but i am unsure of this.

Code:

```
    <select required>
    <option value="select" name="select" title="select">Select A Option</option>>
    <option value="AL" name="AL" title="alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK" name="AK" title="alaska">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ" name="AZ" title="arizona">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR" name="AR" title="arkansas">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA" name="CA" title="california">California</option>
    <option value="CO" name="CO" title="colorado">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT" name="CT" title="connecticut">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE" name="DE" title="delware">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC" name="DC" title="district of columbia">District Of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL" name="FL" title="florida">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA" name="GA" title="georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI" name="HI" title="hawaii">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID" name="ID" title="idaho">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL" name="IL" title="illinois">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN" name="IN" title="indiana">Indiana</option>
    <option value="IA" name="IA" title="iowa">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS" name="KA" title="kansas">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY" name="KY" title="kentucky">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA" name="LA" title="louisiana">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="ME" name="ME" title="maine">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD" name="MD" title="maryland">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA" name="MA" title="massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI" name="MI" title="michigan">Michigan</option>
    <option value="MN" name="MN" title="minnesota">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS" name="MS" title="mississippi">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO" name="MO" title="missouri">Missouri</option>
    <option value="MT" name="MT" title="montana">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE" name="NE" title="nebraska">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NV" name="NV" title="nevada">Nevada</option>
    <option value="NH" name="NH" title="new hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ" name="NJ" title="new jersey">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NM" name="NM" title="new mexico">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="NY" name="NY" title="new york">New York</option>
    <option value="NC" name="NC" title="north carolina">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="ND" name="ND" title="north dakota">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="OH" name="OH" title="ohio" selected>Ohio</option>
    <option value="OK" name="OK" title="oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="OR" name="OR" title="oregon">Oregon</option>
    <option value="PA" name="PA" title="pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI" name="RI" title="rhode island">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC" name="SC" title="south carolina">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="SD" name="SD" title="south dakota">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TN" name="TN" title="tennessee">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="TX" name="TX" title="texas">Texas</option>
    <option value="UT" name="UT" title="utah">Utah</option>
    <option value="VT" name="VT" title="vermont">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA" name="VA" title="virginia">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WA" name="WA" title="washington">Washington</option>
    <option value="WV" name="WV" title="west virginia">West Virginia</option>
    <option value="WI" name="WI" title="wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
    <option value="WY" name="WY" title="wyoming">Wyoming</option>
</select></td>
    <?php if(isset($nostate)) {echo "<span class='errormsg'>Your state is required<br></span>";}?>
</tr>
```

php

```
<?php
// if the submit button has been selected
if(isset($_POST['submit_registration'])) {
    // assign variable to each for control to capture the values
    $first = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address1 = $_POST['address1'];
    $address2 = $_POST['address2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $state = $_POST['state'];
    $postal = $_POST['postal_code'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $distance = $_POST['dist'];
    //assign null values for use with the isset function to identify null fields that are missing a value
    $nofirst = null;
    $nolast = null;
    $noemail = null;
    $noaddress1 = null;
    $noaddress2 = '';
    $nocity = null;
    $nostate= null;
    $nopostal = null;
    $nophone = null;
    $nodistance = null;
    // if value of variable is nothing assign something other than null
    if($first=="") {
        $nofirst = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($last==""){
        $nolast = '';
        $novalue ='';
    }
    if($email=="") {
        $noemail = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($address1=="") {
        $noaddress1 = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($address2=="") {
        $noaddress2 = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($city=="") {
        $nocity = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($state=="") {
        $nostate = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($postal=="") {
        $nopostal = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($phone=="") {
        $nophone = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if($distance=="") {
        $nodistance = '';
        $novalue = '';
    }
    if(isset($novalue)) {$confim = 'Please enter all values';}
        else {
        $insertsql = "INSERT INTO `runner`(`fname`, `lname`,`email`,`address1`,`address2`,`city`,`state`,`postalcode`, `phone`, `distance`) VALUES ('$first', '$last', '$email', '$address1','$address2','$city','$state','$postal','$phone','$distance')";
        mysql_query($connect, $insertsql) or die ("Insert failed: ".mysql_error($connect));
        $confirm = 'Thank you for registering!';
        }
}
?>
```

Any and all help is always appreciated!

Comment: Try condensing the code you posted in your question and focus on the area that's giving you the trouble.

Comment: I condensed the code to what is giving me the trouble at the moment.

Comment: I'm no PHP coder but do you not need to have an id on your select? How does the code know that the dropdown is for `['state']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue might be in the way you declare your select box. Your declaration of the select box name should be in the select tag itself.

You have:

```
<select required>
<option value="select" name="select" title="select">Select A Option</option>>
```

It should be:

```
<select required name="state">
<option value="select">Select A Option</option>
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!